# How do I delete elements from a list based on the boolean values in my list instead of deleting them by index?

Tags: java

I have a list of elements that contains booleans and strings. I have the list output matching what I want, however I need to make it able to delete based on the leading boolean value instead of index. This is the code I have now

```
public class collectionsPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList fruits = new ArrayList();
        fruits.add(false);
        fruits.add("Strawberry");
        fruits.add("Pineapple");
        fruits.add(true);
        fruits.add("Watermelon");
        fruits.add("Lemon");
        fruits.add(false);
        fruits.add("Cantaloupe");
        fruits.add("Grapes");
        fruits.add("Coconut");
        
        fruits.remove(4);
        fruits.remove(4);
        
        System.out.println(fruits);
    }

}
```

The list before the removal looks like this:

```
[false, Strawberry, Pineapple, true, Watermelon, Lemon, false, Cantaloupe, Grapes, Coconut]
```

After the remove calls it looks like this:

```
[false, Strawberry, Pineapple, true, false, Cantaloupe, Grapes, Coconut]
```

I want the strings after every **true** boolean to be deleted. (I know the remove statements look weird, but I have to call them twice because after the first call the index of "Lemon" shifts down by one).

So instead of having the remove at some index, I want to loop through the list and see if the boolean value in the list is true or false. Then if false I want to keep going through the list. However, if it is true, I want to delete the strings in between that boolean and the next boolean. The output should look the same as the output I have with the two remove statements, I just want to be able to do that without having to know how many objects or items are in the list. Is there a way to do this? If any clarification is needed, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Simply put, can you set a flag once you encounter a `true`? keep checking until that next boolean comes , delete those elements , make sure boolean check if before the delete operation so you can unset the flag (once next boolean) and continue iterating the list ! set again and likewise

Comment: related: why do you have such a mixed list? If you any control about the data, consider structuring it in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#iterator()):

```
boolean delete = false;

Iterator<?> iterator = (Iterator<?>) fruits.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object element = iterator.next();
    if (element instanceof Boolean b) {
        delete = b;
    } else if (delete) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may traverse list from the end to avoid mutation of the "tail", something like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList fruits = new ArrayList();
    fruits.add(false);
    fruits.add("Strawberry");
    fruits.add("Pineapple");
    fruits.add(true);
    fruits.add("Watermelon");
    fruits.add("Lemon");
    fruits.add(true);
    fruits.add(false);
    fruits.add("Cantaloupe");
    fruits.add("Grapes");
    fruits.add(true);
    fruits.add("Coconut");

    int end = fruits.size();
    for (int i = end - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(fruits.get(i))) {
            fruits.subList(i + 1, end).clear();
            end = i;
        } else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(fruits.get(i))) {
            end = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fruits);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
ArrayList fruits = new ArrayList();
fruits.add(false);
fruits.add("Strawberry");
fruits.add("Pineapple");
fruits.add(true);
fruits.add("Watermelon");
fruits.add("Lemon");
fruits.add(false);
fruits.add("Cantaloupe");
fruits.add("Grapes");
fruits.add("Coconut");
fruits.add("Lemon");

System.out.println(fruits); //before

ArrayList toRemove = new ArrayList();
boolean deletionFlag = false;

for(int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++){
    Object obj = fruits.get(i);
    if (obj instanceof Boolean){
        deletionFlag = (boolean)obj;
    }else{
        if(deletionFlag) toRemove.add(obj);
    }
}

fruits.removeAll(toRemove);
System.out.println(fruits); //after
```

Comment: Reflection is usually the worst way to do things.  Why not just `if (obj instanceof Boolean)`?

Comment: Well, suppose he had another 3 datatypes in that list, rather than just booleans and Strings. Then you'd need if(...){...}else if(...){...}else if(...){...}else if(...){...}else if(...){...}. Which is much uglier than a switch case block. Of course using reflection is not neccesary, but I don't think it's bad by definition.

Comment: I see nothing in the question that suggests taking different actions for different types.  Boolean values change the deletion flag;  all other values are either kept or deleted, regardless of their type.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Changed answer. And I found out that type pattern matching in switch statements is a preview feature, so if that makes it in I'll be able to use that instead of reflection while still using switch case.